# how to draw a jigsaw using five patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf

Each of the five figures is drawn using a combination of a square, some circles and some sort of shading. I need to draw each of these using a single command  so that they can fit and make a rectangle without gap, for example a 7 times 11 one. Even the arcs can be replaced by a zizag so that they make a rectangle when fit together but this means advanced computation and plotting.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.35]
\draw[fill=cyan] (4.,4.) -- (0.,4.) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white,  draw=none](3.5,2) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=white, draw=none](2,3.5) circle (.8cm);


\draw[fill=cyan] (7,0) -- (11,0) -- (11,4) -- (7,4) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white,  draw=none](10.5,2) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=cyan,  draw=none](6.5,2) circle (.8cm);

\draw[fill=cyan, draw=none](9,4.5) circle (.8cm);


\draw[fill=cyan] (14,0) -- (18,0) -- (18,4) -- (14,4) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=cyan,  draw=none](13.5,2) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=cyan,  draw=none](18.5,2) circle (.8cm);

\draw[fill=white, draw=none](16,3.5) circle (.8cm);

\draw[fill=cyan] (21,0) -- (25,0) -- (25,4) -- (21,4) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white,  draw=none](24.5,2) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=white,  draw=none](21.5,2) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=white,  draw=none](23,.5) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=cyan,  draw=none](23,4.5) circle (.8cm);


\draw[fill=cyan] (28,0) -- (32,0) -- (32,4) -- (28,4) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=cyan,  draw=none](30,4.5) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=cyan,  draw=none](32.5,2) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=white,  draw=none](28.5,2) circle (.8cm);
\draw[fill=white,  draw=none](30,.5) circle (.8cm);

\node at (2, -1) {\small type  1};
\node at (9, -1) {\small type  2};
\node at (16, -1) {\small type  3};
\node at (23, -1) {\small type 4};
\node at (30, -1) {\small type 5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe that the legal patterns are not unique. Which one do you like? Exactly the given one?

Comment: With only these types there are certain restrictions.  There will be one and only one type 3 in each edge.  You cannot have two type 3 in any given row or column.  There can only be one type 4 in any row or column in the  "hole to hole" direction.

Comment: The 7x11 rectangles has more than one configurations yet all of the configurations have the same number of each type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this is a good chance to practice [pgf](/questions/tagged/pgf)'s parser module. See the manual for more information.

The foreground layer is actually unnecessary. But since the *pocket* is drawn by a white circle, I have to draw the *tab* on a different layer.

The clipping syntax, `shift` and `scale` are unnecessary, too. But that means you have to recode your pieces.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{parser}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character 1}{\def\jigsawtype{1}}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character 2}{\def\jigsawtype{2}}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character 3}{\def\jigsawtype{3}}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character 4}{\def\jigsawtype{4}}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character 5}{\def\jigsawtype{5}}

\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the letter A}   {\def\jigsawangle{0}}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character <}{\def\jigsawangle{90}}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the letter V}   {\def\jigsawangle{180}}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character >}{\def\jigsawangle{-90}}

\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{blank space \space}{}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character :}{\jigsawstart}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character ,}{\jigsawdrawone}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character ;}{\jigsawnewline}
\pgfparserdef{jigsaw}{all}{the character .}{\jigsawend}


\def\jigsawstart{
    \path coordinate(line begin)coordinate(curser);
}
\def\jigsawdrawone{
    \draw(curser)pic[rotate=\jigsawangle]{jigsaw \jigsawtype};
    \path(curser)++(1,0)coordinate(curser);
}
\def\jigsawnewline{
    \path(line begin)++(0,-1)coordinate(line begin)coordinate(curser);
}
\def\jigsawend{
    \pgfparserswitch{final}
}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    sq/.style={cyan,draw=white,line width=.05cm},
    cl/.style={clip,fill=none},
    fc/.style={cyan},
    fw/.style={white},
    jigsaw 1/.pic={
        \tikzset{scale=.25,shift={(-2,-2)}}
        \fill[sq](4,4)--(0,4)--(0,0)--(4,0)--cycle;
        \fill[cl](4,4)--(0,4)--(0,0)--(4,0)--cycle;
        \fill[fw](3.5,2)circle(.9);
        \fill[fw](2,3.5)circle(.9);
    },
    jigsaw 2/.pic={
        \tikzset{scale=.25,shift={(-9,-2)}}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \fill[fc](6.5,2)circle(.7);
        \fill[fc](9,4.5)circle(.7);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \fill[sq](7,0)--(11,0)--(11,4)--(7,4)--cycle;
        \fill[cl](7,0)--(11,0)--(11,4)--(7,4)--cycle;
        \fill[fw](10.5,2)circle(.9);
    },
    jigsaw 3/.pic={
        \tikzset{scale=.25,shift={(-16,-2)}}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \fill[fc](13.5,2)circle(.7);
        \fill[fc](18.5,2)circle(.7);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \fill[sq](14,0)--(18,0)--(18,4)--(14,4)--cycle;
        \fill[cl](14,0)--(18,0)--(18,4)--(14,4)--cycle;
        \fill[fw](16,3.5)circle(.9);
    },
    jigsaw 4/.pic={
        \tikzset{scale=.25,shift={(-23,-2)}}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \fill[fc](23,4.5)circle(.7);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \fill[sq](21,0)--(25,0)--(25,4)--(21,4)--cycle;
        \fill[cl](21,0)--(25,0)--(25,4)--(21,4)--cycle;
        \fill[fw](24.5,2)circle(.9);
        \fill[fw](21.5,2)circle(.9);
        \fill[fw](23,.5)circle(.9);
    },
    jigsaw 5/.pic={
        \tikzset{scale=.25,shift={(-30,-2)}}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \fill[fc](30,4.5)circle(.7);
        \fill[fc](32.5,2)circle(.7);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \fill[sq](28,0)--(32,0)--(32,4)--(28,4)--cycle;
        \fill[cl](28,0)--(32,0)--(32,4)--(28,4)--cycle;
        \fill[fw](28.5,2)circle(.9);
        \fill[fw](30,.5)circle(.9);
    }
}

\tikz{
    \pgfparserparse{jigsaw}:
        1>,3V,2V,2V,2V,2V,2V,2V,2V,1V,;
        2>,5A,4>,5>,5>,5>,5>,5>,5>,3<,;
        2>,4A,5<,5V,5V,5V,5V,5V,5V,2<,;
        2>,5A,4A,5V,5V,5V,5V,5V,5V,2<,;
        2>,5A,4A,5V,5V,5V,5V,5V,5V,2<,;
        3>,5<,5<,4<,4<,4<,4<,5<,5V,2<,;
        1A,2A,2A,2A,2A,2A,2A,2A,3A,1<,.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Found a overlap on the lower right corner; hope it does not harm.

Comment: You could sell this as a game "find the one overlap in this pattern" - it took me quite a bit to find it :)

Comment: Or, put one thousand ducks on a page and find the one with red-white shirt and blue pants.

Comment: We could make a whole book with such riddles :)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of worrying yourself how to puzzle together your jigsaw pieces, you could use the `jigsaw` package to automatically create a pattern of your desired dimensions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{jigsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[cyan] (0,0) rectangle (11,7);
  \jigsaw{11}{7}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the trick is to not try to puzzle matching pieces together, but to draw only every second line :)