# doubts about the process of creating The TikZlings package

Tags: packages, package-writing

I would like to know what techniques were used by @samcarter to draw the figures from the package https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings. If you have some sample code to show I will also be grateful.

Comment: Unfortunately the only person who can answer that has left this site for the time being. I imagine, though, that she used some vector graphics software (I saw her speaking about Inkscape once or twice) and then converted the drawing to Ti*k*Z code. I imagine this because the coordinates in the pictures have 3 to 4 decimal places, so it looks like generated code.

Comment: I only can say something about the koala, but as @PhelypeOleinik is saying the author of the package is not around, which is really really sad (not only the fact but also the circumstances that caused it).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, i do not know the method of converting images generated in Inkscape to TiKz but I will try to find some example of this process. Would the result be something similar to this structure https://github.com/joulev/TikZ-figures/blob/master/Laika/main.tex ?

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah Oh, I don't know either. There is this [`svg2tikz`](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) extension for Inkscape, but I never managed to get it working. When I need to use an SVG path in Ti*k*Z I load the `svg.path` library and use the SVG code directly.

Comment: I can not say but sam was good at minimising curves in what seemed a simple fashion see the jigsaw pieces here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446296/170109 The tikzlings (built over time) drew (pun) on prior code in a reusable fashion so the cats body is defined as \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \cat@part@draw[\cat@body] (0.3, 0.5) .. controls (0.55, 0.87) and (0.73, 1.50) .. (1.05, 1.65) .. controls (1.32, 1.77) and (1.76, 1.34) .. (1.56,1.33) .. controls (0.92, 2.03) and (0.86, 0.60) .. (0.5, 0.37) -- cycle;
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

Comment: Thanks @KJO, I will try the maximum of useful conclusions for my learning on the subject that you related to my question.

Comment: See samcarter reply here: https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings/issues/5.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you :).