# Is there a talk icon in LaTex?

Tags: symbols, icon

I'm currently looking for a "talk icon" in LaTex and couldn't find one in "The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List". Does anybody know if there is some kind of talk icon for LaTex (something like this: [image])?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can always build your own. That way you can change details, if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\TalkingHead[1][]{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\draw[xscale=-1,line width=pi*1mm] (-1,-4) to[out=50,in=-90,looseness=1.4] (-1,-3) to[out=-160,in=0]
   (-2,-3.2) to[out=180,in=-120] (-2.7,-2) to[out=120,in=-120] (-2.9,-1.5)
   to[out=120,in=-120] (-2.95,-1.1) to[out=60,in=-30] (-3.2,-0.9)
   to[out=150,in=-120] (-3,0.4) to[out=60,in=-90] (-3,1.2) 
   to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.8] (3.3,1.2)
   to[out=-90,in=90,looseness=0.8] (2,-2)
   to[out=-90,in=150,looseness=0.8] (3.2,-4) -- cycle;
  \draw[line width=pi*1mm,shift={(pi,-pi/2)}] 
    foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(45:\X) arc[start angle=45,end
  angle=-45,radius=\X]};
\end{tikzpicture}}{Q}}
\begin{document}
\TalkingHead

{\Huge\TalkingHead}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\scalerel*` is used to scale the symbol with the font size.

P.S. If you are puzzled about the origin of the head contour: [this solves the puzzle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499862).

There are many ways to make it more versatile, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480818).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\makeatletter% cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480818
\DeclareRobustCommand{\checkbold}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24635/121799
 \def#1{0}%
 \edef\@tempa{\f@series}\edef\@tempb{\bfseries@rm}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \fi%
 \edef\@tempb{\bfseries@sf}%
 \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
  \def#1{1}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
\newcommand\TalkingHead[1][]{\checkbold\tmp%
\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width={(1+0.67*\tmp)*pi*1mm},#1]
\path[use as bounding box] (-3.7,-4.2) rectangle (6.4,4.72);
\draw[xscale=-1] (-1,-4) to[out=50,in=-90,looseness=1.4] (-1,-3) to[out=-160,in=0]
   (-2,-3.2) to[out=180,in=-120] (-2.7,-2) to[out=120,in=-120] (-2.9,-1.5)
   to[out=120,in=-120] (-2.95,-1.1) to[out=60,in=-30] (-3.2,-0.9)
   to[out=150,in=-120] (-3,0.4) to[out=60,in=-90] (-3,1.2) 
   to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.8] (3.3,1.2)
   to[out=-90,in=90,looseness=0.8] (2,-2)
   to[out=-90,in=150,looseness=0.8] (3.2,-4) -- cycle;
  \draw[shift={(pi,-pi/2)}] 
    foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(45:\X) arc[start angle=45,end
  angle=-45,radius=\X]};
\end{tikzpicture}}{B}}
\begin{document}
Ppf \TalkingHead\space blub\par 
{\bfseries Ppf \TalkingHead\space blub}\par

\bigskip
{\Huge Ppf \TalkingHead\space blub\par
{\bfseries Ppf \TalkingHead\space blub}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And indeed, I was puzzled about the head contour.

Answer (score 1):

To a Martian anthropologist, the implementation of the Unicode speaking head emoji (U+1F5E3), also known as 'rated for strong language', looks more like the guy who started the latest planetary shutdown.

[image: speaking]

The Tikz version, with its dolphin-like sound waves, is much better.