# Jigsaw puzzle with text in each piece

Tags: tikz-pgf, puzzle

I am following the second answer from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446292/36296) and I want to add text to each piece of the puzzle, centered in the middle. What should be added? Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\side}[1]{
(0.5,0.5) -- 
(0.0,#1*0.00) .. controls (0.0,#1*0.00) and (0.4,#1*-0.04) .. 
(0.4,#1*0.04) .. controls (0.4,#1*0.11) and (0.2,#1*0.26) .. 
(0.5,#1*0.26) .. controls (0.8,#1*0.26) and (0.6,#1*0.11) .. 
(0.6,#1*0.04) .. controls (0.6,#1*-0.04) and (1.0,#1*0.00) .. 
(1.0,#1*0.00)
}

\newcommand{\piece}[5][white]{
    \fill[#1] 
    \side{#2}
    [rotate around={90:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#3} 
    [rotate around={180:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#4} 
    [rotate around={270:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#5} 
    -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
    \piece[red]{1}{1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \piece[blue]{1}{-1}{-1}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
    \piece[green]{1}{0}{1}{0}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[green]{1}{-1}{0}{-1}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[red]{1}{-1}{1}{-1}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[blue]{-1}{0}{1}{-1}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[blue]{0}{-1}{0}{-1}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[green]{0}{-1}{1}{-1}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[red]{0}{0}{1}{1}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added an extra argument (`#6`) to `\piece`, and this to the end of its definition" `\node [white] at (.5,.5) {#6};`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\side}[1]{
(0.5,0.5) -- 
(0.0,#1*0.00) .. controls (0.0,#1*0.00) and (0.4,#1*-0.04) .. 
(0.4,#1*0.04) .. controls (0.4,#1*0.11) and (0.2,#1*0.26) .. 
(0.5,#1*0.26) .. controls (0.8,#1*0.26) and (0.6,#1*0.11) .. 
(0.6,#1*0.04) .. controls (0.6,#1*-0.04) and (1.0,#1*0.00) .. 
(1.0,#1*0.00)
}

\newcommand{\piece}[6][white]{
    \fill[#1]
    \side{#2}
    [rotate around={90:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#3} 
    [rotate around={180:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#4} 
    [rotate around={270:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#5} 
    -- cycle;
    \node [white] at (.5,.5) {#6};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
    \piece[red]{1}{1}{0}{0}{A}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \piece[blue]{1}{-1}{-1}{0}{B}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
    \piece[green]{1}{0}{1}{0}{C}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[green]{1}{-1}{0}{-1}{D}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[red]{1}{-1}{1}{-1}{E}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[blue]{-1}{0}{1}{-1}{F}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[blue]{0}{-1}{0}{-1}{G}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[green]{0}{-1}{1}{-1}{H}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[red]{0}{0}{1}{1}{I}
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted to be able to add more text, I would recommend invoking as  `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]` (or some other value).  This will grow the size of the pieces without changing the size of the overlaid text.  For example, with a scale of 2, it looks thus:

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Based on an OP follow up: how to get an outline?  And how to add more text?

Two things need to change.  The `\fill[#1]` command is changed to `\draw[#1,postaction={fill=gray!10}]` and the interior `\node`'s color may need re-evaluation, here as `\node [black]`.

To increase the amount of text in the puzzle piece, I use a `\Centerstack` from the `stackengine` package.  I also grew the `scale=` of the `tikzpicture`, which can always be shrunk down later, after the fact.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\newcommand{\side}[1]{
(0.5,0.5) -- 
(0.0,#1*0.00) .. controls (0.0,#1*0.00) and (0.4,#1*-0.04) .. 
(0.4,#1*0.04) .. controls (0.4,#1*0.11) and (0.2,#1*0.26) .. 
(0.5,#1*0.26) .. controls (0.8,#1*0.26) and (0.6,#1*0.11) .. 
(0.6,#1*0.04) .. controls (0.6,#1*-0.04) and (1.0,#1*0.00) .. 
(1.0,#1*0.00)
}

\newcommand{\piece}[6][white]{
    \draw[#1,postaction={fill=gray!10}]
    \side{#2}
    [rotate around={90:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#3} 
    [rotate around={180:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#4} 
    [rotate around={270:(0.5,0.5)}] \side{#5} 
    -- cycle;
    \node [black] at (.5,.5) {\Centerstack{#6}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.5]

\begin{scope}
    \piece[red]{1}{1}{0}{0}{my text\\goes right\\here}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \piece[blue]{1}{-1}{-1}{0}{B}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
    \piece[green]{1}{0}{1}{0}{C}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[green]{1}{-1}{0}{-1}{D}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[red]{1}{-1}{1}{-1}{E}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \piece[blue]{-1}{0}{1}{-1}{F}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[blue]{0}{-1}{0}{-1}{G}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[green]{0}{-1}{1}{-1}{H}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \piece[red]{0}{0}{1}{1}{I}
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to ask......What about the outline of each piece? The code has `\fill`. However, by adding `\draw` didn't work like a traditional node...

Comment: @aripod Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**

Comment: That worked perfectly!
I currently have `font=\sffamily\tiny` to make the text fit (I have more text, not letters). That's why I chose \tiny. I would like to have a larger font but that makes the text overlap with the edges. Is it possible to make the pieces larger?

Comment: @aripod As I indicated in my answer, the `scale=` parameter will grow the figure, which you can later scale down.  Also, you could use, for example, a `\Centerstack`  (from the `stackengine` package) to get multi-line text in the puzzle piece.

Comment: @aripod Please see my updated **SUPPLEMENT**

Comment: Ugh, yes! I left scale at 2 and missed it! Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can draw jigsaw pieces including text like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{jigsaw}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={draw},
  foo/.style={draw=none,gray,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,1) pic [fill=red] {piece={1}{1}{0}{0}} node[foo] {A};
\path (1,1) pic [fill=green] {piece={1}{0}{0}{-1}} node[foo] {B};
\path (0,0) pic [fill=blue] {piece={0}{-1}{-1}{0}} node[foo] {C};
\path (1,0) pic [fill=yellow] {piece={0}{0}{-1}{1}} node[foo] {D};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]